# Absolute convergence of series and absolute integrability of function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

There is something I cannot get an intuitive feel for:

Because of the Cauchy criterion it's quite easy to show that if $\sum |f_n|$ converges, then $\sum f_n$ converges.

On the other hand it is not the case that if $\int |f|$ exits (i.e. $|f|$ is integrable) that then $\int f$ exists. An easy example is a modified Dirichlet function where $f(x) = 1 \enspace \mathrm{if} \enspace  x\ \in \mathbb Q$ and $-1$ otherwise.

So (I think) I understand the proof, but what is a possibly deeper underlying reason if any? After all the integral is loosely speaking a sum, but I appreciate that a Cauchy criterion for a series as partition interval goes to zero is maybe not possible to construct.

Comment: This very much depends on what one means by "integrable".  E.g. both the modified Dirichlet function and its absolute value (say, restricted to some interval) are Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: @rafexiap Yes sorry, I mean in this case Riemann integrability.

Comment: Part of the issue is that the Darboux sums depend on how much a function varies on some interval.  You came up with an example, where $|f|$ varies little but $f$ varies a lot.

Comment: @rafexiap if $A$ is not measurable, then $f = \mathbb I_A - 1/2$ is not Lebesgue integrable while $|f|$ is, so it doesn't change much.

Comment: Function can fail to be (improper) integrable for two reasons: it is too discontinuous (have positive measure of discontinuity points in Riemann case, be non-measurable in Lebesgue), or it's "good" but is too big. Cauchy criterion checks only for the second. It works for series without restriction because the first case can't happen for series. Formally, if $f$ is continuous a.e. and $|f|$ is Riemann-integrable, then $f$ is Riemann-integrable - we need to add the first condition.

Comment: @mihaild Thanks, I'll mull over the statement "Cauchy criterion checks only for the second", which makes sense as continuity is difficult to define on countable sets such as $\mathbb N$. The second part of your comment, if $f$ is continuous a.e., then it is automatically Lebesgue integrable right? So in that case I don't think I even have to check whether $|f|$ is Lebesgue integrable or not. (I know I mentioned Riemann integrability first, so I am drifting here).

Comment: No, $f(x) = 1/x$ if $x \neq 0$, $f(0) = 0$ is continuous almost everywhere but not Lebesgue integrable on $[-1, 1]$.

Comment: @mihaild Ah yes, of course.